# Crop ODS PDF output to edge of histogram

Tags: sas

I'm creating a histogram as follows:

```
    options papersize=(10in 10in);
    goptions device=pdfc vsize=4in htext=10ptk; 
    Options topmargin="0in" bottommargin="0in" leftmargin="0in" rightmargin="0in";
    ods pdf file="&folder/histo1.pdf";
    goptions hsize=10in vsize=10in border;
    ods select where=(_name_ ?  'Histogr');
    proc univariate data=phd.customers;
            var BetCount;
          histogram BetCount / name='histogr';
    run;
    ods pdf close;
```

I want to have an output pdf similar to this one, with no margins and crop to the edge of the histogram: http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/h_example_22.pdf

Thanks for any help at all on this.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  Seems to me a better way is to just make the histogram into a jpeg or png or whatever, if you just want the picture.  PDF doesn't give you any advantage here, and it would be completely unprintable with no margins.

Comment: I don't need to print this, it will be embedded in a 3x2 frame of six graphs in a Latex document. All the examples of latex documents with embedded graphs that I've seen use PDF rather than PNG or JPEG. If cropping the image was possible with PNG, I would use that.

Comment: Outputting to HTML or anything else would produce a PNG that's fairly well cropped (or whatever you asked it to produce with the driver option).  Not sure it's easy to get better than that, but you could probably have LaTeX crop things beyond that if needed.